# Undo unwanted site reset

Tags: 2013, site, versioning

A user claims to have made changes to a Sharepoint 2013 site as recently as yesterday.

When they checked again this morning the changes had been lost. They say they saved etc but when I have looked through the system it displays the modified dates as April of this year, which I assume was the day the site was created.

Any ideas as to what happened and perhaps more importantly how I may be able to bring the changes back?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have a backup of the content database? If yes, you can just restore it. Changes will be reflected.

Comment: Yeah we do but it goes to an external company who aren't the greatest. I was hoping for a solution that would avoid them really. We were aware of this solution though so thank you for the confirmation.